# How to view source code of Gradle tasks defined in plugins using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

In Android Studio Gradle tab I'm able to find `run` task from application plugin.

[image: List of tasks of AS project]

I want to view source code of this task.

Right click -> Jump to Source is disabled for this task.

How to view source code of tasks defined in plugins using Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

input command like:

```
./gradlew help --task "${taskName}"
```

terminal will show you class, just search the class.